# Image automatically rotate with image view in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to pick the image from gallery and set to imageview. Image was set but the image automatically set with horizontal view. I want to set vertical view.

My code is:

```
public void edit_profile_pic(View view) 
{
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,   Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            System.out.println(selectedImage);
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_profile_picture);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Xml File:

```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/profile_profile_picture"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_components"
      android:src="@drawable/profile_picture"        
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:onClick="edit_profile_pic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the image you are selecting is a landscape image. Try selecting the portrait image, you will get a in vertical view.

And if you want to have all the images in vertical view, then you need to give a custom width and height to your `ImageView` Control.

also set the `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` on imageview control

Comment: i already give custom width and height only but it is not work.(Fahim)

Comment: try the updated answer.  and tell which orientation image u r selecting and share me your xml file

Comment: how to i share xml file